# Xpages compatibility issues with OneUI and Domino HCL 11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, lotus-domino, ibm-oneui

I am testing several xpages applications that use OneUi on Domino 11. I found that a lot doesn't work, even if the X-UA-Compatible meta tag for Edge. Are there any resources I can apply to remove most errors? If compiling in HCL Designer 11, does it solve the problem? All the alternatives that I evaluated (X-UA-Compatible or bootstrap) will be a lot of work. There is some easy way.
In addition, I am testing the xpages applications, which only work via the browser, in IE11, where Domino automatically forces the compatibility mode of iE 7. In this context, the extensios liibrary dialog box are not displayed, the components collapse all / expand all and pagination Do not work. On the other hand, if I set the compatibility mode to 11, the screens are deformed and the dialog box do not work either. If I apply bootstrap, the layout is formatted, but I can't even open a document based on an xpages.

Comment: Please add more details on what you have problems with. I have an application using OneUI that works as expected on Domino 11